# ccavenue softon/indipay how to get auth id laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

$members_id = Auth::id();

// Get the last inserted invoice ID for the user
$invoices = $this->invoice->where('members_id', $members_id)->latest('id')->value('id');
this Two value are null after Payment response how to get $members_id $invoices Any possible ?

```
    public function paymentResponse(Request $request)
    
    {
        
        
// Get the authenticated user's ID
$members_id = Auth::id();

// Get the last inserted invoice ID for the user
$invoices = $this->invoice->where('members_id', $members_id)->latest('id')->value('id');

// For the default gateway
$response = Indipay::response($request);
$response['members_id'] = $members_id; // Corrected the array key syntax
$response['invoice_id'] = $invoices; // Corrected the array key syntax

// For other than the default gateway (e.g., CCAvenue)
$response = Indipay::gateway('CCAvenue')->response($request);
$response['members_id'] = $members_id; // Corrected the array key syntax
$response['invoice_id'] = $invoices; // Corrected the array key syntax

// Insert the payment response data into the 'payments' table
DB::table('payments')->insert($response);

if($response['order_status'] == 'success'){

        // Display a success toast message
        Alert::toast('Payment successful!', 'success');
             return redirect()->route('admin.invoice.membership_details.view');  

}
else{
   Alert::toast('Payment cancelled!', 'error');

     return redirect()->route('admin.invoice.membership_details.view');  
}
        // dd($response);
    
    }
```

Comment: How does this method get invoked, are we talking about a webhook here, or a redirect happening inside the user's browser? If the latter, have you checked whether your system is able to pick up the session at all, after the redirect? If not, check the `SameSite` value your session id cookie gets set with.